# Is it possible to intercept http requests not initiated by client using javascript?

Tags: javascript, http, spotify

The title is my issue.

I'm trying to make an in sync working progress bar for a custom Spotify player.

At the moment, the API does not offer any solution to get information in realtime about the playback. Therefore, I'm thinking, might be possible to exploit the arrival of the request that holds the song to start a timer locally.

The problem for this solution, is I don't know how to intercept requests not initiated by the client.

I've looked up service workers, and it seemed like they're intercepting requests only if initiated by client.

Looking up the webRequestAPI at the moment, and seems like this one might do it. Howerver, if possible, I'd rather not have stuff to install on the client side.

**So long story short, is it possible to intercept requests not initiated by the client ? If yes, how one should proceed ?**

Thanks for reading. I'm eager to read you answers.

Comment: What do you mean 'not initiated by the client'. Like no initiated by client code? so like image requests, ect? If that's the case you might want to look at service workers. They are commonly used to intercept outbound requests for caching, preloading, ect. See [this](https://livebook.manning.com/book/progressive-web-apps/chapter-4/25) write up to get you started.

Comment: HTTP requests are always initiated "by the client" (a server cannot initiate an HTTP request to a client). If you mean intercept requests not made by the *browser*, the answer is no, since the browser is purposefully kept separate from other processes.

Comment: Not initiated by the client means, not initiated by client code yeah, like I did not write a  xhr request to provoke it. But still, it's a consequence of one I've made, and some server is sending it to me after some time. I don't know about image requests atm... I'd actually would like something similar to postman's interceptors but within a js browser.